# acme.sh: how to reactivate account

Tags: acme.sh

acme.sh started to fail when trying to issue a cert.

Running this command:

`/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --debug --force --issue -k 2048 -d todase.smartomato.ru -w /var/www/smartomato/current/public/`

leads to this error:

```
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Using config home:/root/.acme.sh
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Running cmd: issue
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _main_domain='todase.smartomato.ru'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _alt_domains='no'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Using config home:/root/.acme.sh
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] default_acme_server
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] ACME_DIRECTORY='https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] DOMAIN_PATH='/root/.acme.sh/todase.smartomato.ru'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Le_NextRenewTime
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Using ACME_DIRECTORY: https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _init api for server: https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _on_before_issue
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _chk_main_domain='todase.smartomato.ru'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _chk_alt_domains
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Le_LocalAddress
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] d='todase.smartomato.ru'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Check for domain='todase.smartomato.ru'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _currentRoot='/var/www/smartomato/current/public/'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] d
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _saved_account_key_hash is not changed, skip register account.
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Read key length:2048
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _createcsr
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] d
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] url='https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/newOrder'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] payload='{"identifiers": [{"type":"dns","value":"todase.smartomato.ru"}]}'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] RSA key
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] HEAD
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _post_url='https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/newNonce'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] _CURL='curl --silent --dump-header /root/.acme.sh/http.header  -L  -g  -I  '
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] _ret='0'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] POST
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] _post_url='https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/newOrder'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] _CURL='curl --silent --dump-header /root/.acme.sh/http.header  -L  -g '
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] _ret='0'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] code='401'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] Le_LinkOrder
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] Le_OrderFinalize
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] Create new order error. Le_OrderFinalize not found. {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized","status":401,"detail":"The account has been deactivated"}
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] pid
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] No need to restore nginx, skip.
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] _clearupdns
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] dns_entries
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] skip dns.
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] _on_issue_err
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] Please add '--debug' or '--log' to check more details.
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] See: https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/How-to-debug-acme.sh
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] socat doesn't exist.
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:20 MSK 2023] Diagnosis versions: 
openssl:openssl
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
apache:
apache doesn't exist.
nginx:
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
socat:
https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh
v3.0.6
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Using CA: https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Single domain='todase.smartomato.ru'
[Tue Mar 28 14:23:19 MSK 2023] Getting domain auth token for each domain
```

I tried to register account with:

`/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --register-account -m shalpack@gmail.com`

```
[Tue Mar 28 14:32:54 MSK 2023] Registering account: https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90
[Tue Mar 28 14:32:55 MSK 2023] Already registered
[Tue Mar 28 14:32:55 MSK 2023] ACCOUNT_THUMBPRINT='w0b36HFkoxIty2f5A96OGDph3RjWXmreOX5YiCkdD_A'
```

Also I tried other email address, but the error is still reproducing.

The interesting thing is that the error occurred by itself - I haven't made any recent changes to acme.sh.

How can I reactivate or re-register the account?